# ceiling fan install red wire /white wire

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

My kitchen had a ceiling light with 2 switches. I removed the light fixture and I want to install a ceiling fan and light that has a remote control.

I connected the black wire from the fan to the black wire in the box and the white wire from the fan to the red wire in the box. The light and fan work from the remote but not from the wall switch. Is this correct?

Also, when I turn the fan and light off at night using the remote at around 10 pm, we find the fan OR the light will be on around 2-3am and this will happen even with the light switches in the OFF position and the battery REMOVED from the remote. Why would that happen?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Were the two switches for the existing lamp three-way, so that you could turn the lamp on or off from either one? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "The white wire from the fan to the red wire from the box"  this is weird.  White wire from fan should go to neutral. Can you update with a picture of the fan box and switch box?

Comment: You're also going to have to decide if you're going to use the switches or the remote... if you turn off the switches, then the remote wont work and vice verses.

Comment: Make/model of fan/light/remote?

Comment: What country are you in?  Red and black sounds like UK, AU or NZ.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the fan and switch boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Red is usually used for "switched hot". Black is typically for the hot side, and white is for neutral. I would expect you to wire black to black, white to white, and bare/green to bare/green. Then you'd control the ceiling fan with the remote, NOT the switch.